# Vibration when turning

Tags: honda, vibration, wheel-bearing, cv-joint

I don't have a lot of experience, but I try to do what I can myself. I am trying to diagnose a vibration in the frontend of a 2011 Honda Pilot 2wd. This vibration is coming from the driver front wheel and gets worse when I turn passenger.

Recently, I replaced the compliance bushing right before a long road trip. In doing so, I separated the boot from the hub inboard. I repacked the bearings and was ready to go. About 500 miles from home, I noticed the grease had all dumped out. I decided to drive home anyway and fix it when I got there. Once home, I pulled the cv axle out, repacked it, put it back in. The vibration developed either on the way home or after I repacked the axle after the trip.

The vibration continued, and for some reason I thought it was the cv axle, so I replaced it, but it made no difference. Now I believe it is a bad wheel bearing. I recorded a [video](https://photos.app.goo.gl/Dm8IGGMNEcbcl4rl2) of the sound.

Comment: Hmmm, sounds like there may be something like sand or grit in the bearings. However, when I first listened to the video, I thought it was something rubbing on the disc.

Because it's a rythmic sound, we can just assume it's something near the hub assembly because the speed of the scraping sound was the same as the CV boot clip spinning. It's something to do with that drive axle, one of the constant velocity bearings/boots or the hub itself.

Comment: I'm leaning towards replacing the bearings. Do you think that's a good start?

Comment: Place your hand on the spring and spin the wheel by hand. If the bearing is bad you'll feel a vibration in the spring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bad wheel hub/bearing unit.